# Facebook like count not working on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

Hope you can help with the below, which I've spent most of this weekend trying to resolve but to no avail.

I use a social share and vote plugin on my website, which works perfectly for G+ Twitter Pinterest etc etc. However my facebook like button simply does not want to work.

Example, yesterday I posted this on my websites facebook page.
https://www.facebook.com/116091541779464/photos/a.496114153777199.1073741829.116091541779464/696621417059804/?type=1

As you can see, this links to this page of my website which has its like, share, +1 counts etc at the bottom: http://www.superluigibros.com/evolution-of-mario

As you can see from the Facebook post it has 85 likes. Yet the website shows only 1 like?

The social plugin that I use asks for an App ID. I have created, and activated an App in Facebook and put the App ID in the relevant field of the plugin.

However I am not sure that the App is actually set up properly on the Facebook side, or maybe it lacks the permission to actually count the likes?

The only other point of note is that I am using another Facebook widget (the one that shows who likes our page) in a seperate module. Could this be conflicting in some way?

If anyone could help would be greatly appreciated. I really dont understand whats up with it

Best regards

Luke

Answer (score 0):

This is the case because those are two completely different things:

- On http://www.superluigibros.com/evolution-of-mario the number of likes is the number of times the URL was liked
- With https://www.facebook.com/116091541779464/photos/a.496114153777199.1073741829.116091541779464/696621417059804/?type=1 you just posted an image also present on your page to your Facebook pages. The like count show the likes only for this image

So, what you need to do is to add the OpenGraph tags properly to your website, as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-creating Then, you shouldn't share just an image on your Facebook page's feed, but the URL instead. FB will then pull the content for the image etc. from your website upon sharing.

Answer (score -1):

The like counter in your facebook post is handled separately from the likes of your website page. Each "like" that your post receive doesn't count towards the site's like counter.

EDIT: I've just tested your site's like counter, and it's counting correctly as I have just liked it myself.